# Responsive scaling of hero images in different screen widths

Tags: jquery, html, css, scaling, responsive

This is the sample I want to have: http://www.garysheng.com/
it's not mine

in mobile the background image still scales and the picture is accurately centered

[How am i going to achieve this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w4pi.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried? Take a look with the css properties `background-size: cover` and others like `height: 100vh`...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use some basic CSS rules like `background-size` and `background-position`.

In order for you to do this, your stylesheet may look something similar to this:

```
.item-class {
    background-image: url('url');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Or by simply using the shorthand version:

```
.item-class {
    background: url('url') no-repeat center center/cover;
}
```

Your `.item-class` object should have a height of `100vh` in order for it to behave the same way as that Gary Sheng website you like.

Comment: my code is this it  doesnt work  background: url('../images/bg.jpg') center no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  
    min-height:100vh;
    overflow:hidden;

Comment: The mentioned page uses custom JS code, so I don't think you can achieve the same result using css only.

Comment: @rieb , use the code I have provided, yours seem to be a bit messy. Also, a `min-height` of `100vh` is not a good setting, simply apply a `height` and manipulate that with media queries if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete sample. I tried to clear it up as much as possible, but pay attention to the following:

- There are references to external files and jQuery
- Custom JS code is extracted from minified version and is a bit messy, please debug and adjust it.
- JSFiddle inline CSS is quite important for small screens.

https://jsfiddle.net/mzeyt6p8/2/

To see result use the following link: https://jsfiddle.net/mzeyt6p8/2/embedded/result/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://static-assets.strikinglycdn.com/assets/B4E0UXLKGAJ/_reset-d71ac2794e9667b03908f392a514acc4.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://static-assets.strikinglycdn.com/assets/B4E0UXLKGAJ/themes/fresh/main_v4-0a28326edfc0328a9a1f8feb08e3d1d2.css">
```

To make it more clear, here is a complete sample that should work locally.

**index.html**

```
<html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>I'm Gary Sheng</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://static-assets.strikinglycdn.com/assets/B4E0UXLKGAJ/_reset-d71ac2794e9667b03908f392a514acc4.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://static-assets.strikinglycdn.com/assets/B4E0UXLKGAJ/themes/fresh/main_v4-0a28326edfc0328a9a1f8feb08e3d1d2.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        @media only screen and (max-width: 727px) {
            .s-bg-image { background-position: 80% !important; }
        }

        .s-bg-image {
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-color: transparent;
            background-position: 50% 50%;
            background-image: url('http://res.cloudinary.com/hrscywv4p/image/upload/c_limit,f_auto,fl_progressive,h_1500,q_90,w_2000/v1/9621/Untitled-1_msxftc.jpg');
            padding-top: 135px;
            padding-bottom: 136px;
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="size.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="s-content" class="s-variation-default s-custom-colors s-font-heading-open-sans s-font-title-raleway s-font-body-open-sans" lang="en">
        <div class="page-wrapper">
            <ul class="slides s-page-1" style="display: block; opacity: 1;">
                <li class="slide s-section-1" id="section-f_de4cf792-9bd2-4c70-85f6-5117032a5a08">
                    <div>
                        <div id="image_header" class="s-bg-image s-bg-light-text s-new-title-section s-section transition"><!-- react-text: 51 -->
                            <div class="container">Test</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <h1>Content</h1>
                <p style="font-size: 55px; padding: 10px;">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**size.js**

```
function updatePaddings() {
    var imageHeader = $("#image_header");
    var smallWindow = $(window).width() <= 727 || $(window).height() < 400;

    var content = imageHeader.find(".container").first()
    var contentHeight = content.height();

    var topPaddingInitial = imageHeader.css("paddingTop");
    var bottomPaddingInitial = imageHeader.css("paddingBottom");
    imageHeader.css("paddingTop", "");
    imageHeader.css("paddingBottom", "");
    var d = Math.min(100, parseInt(imageHeader.css("padding-top"), 10))
    var c = Math.min(100, parseInt(imageHeader.css("padding-bottom"), 10))

    var windowHeight = $(window).outerHeight();

    var tempPadding = .5 * (windowHeight - contentHeight)

    var newPaddingTop = Math.max(Math.min(450, Math.floor(tempPadding)), d)
    var newPaddingBottom = Math.max(Math.min(450, Math.ceil(tempPadding)), c)

    imageHeader.css("paddingTop", newPaddingTop);
    imageHeader.css("paddingBottom", newPaddingBottom);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    updatePaddings();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    updatePaddings();
});
```

Comment: hi @sasha_gud it seems it only works on jsfiddle. the smooth scaling isnt working on local

Comment: @rieb I've added source code of two files. It works the same way locally as on jsfiddle.

Comment: did you put it on the <head>or before the </body> tag? @sasha_gud

Comment: @rieb I'm not sure what exactly you mean. Two files `index.html` and `size.js` are provided completely. If you place them in the same local folder and open `index.html`, it should work the same way as jsfiddle. The files include all JS, CSS and HTML that is needed.